# Attribute based exception logging in a Windows Form App

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

I've started work on an existing Windows Forms application for my work with a team of five other developers. It is my understanding that the team will be expanding to new developers as well. The project is fairly large and still has new features to be added. I've developed some concern for how the project handles exceptions in service methods. Currently, **almost every service method** follows this structure:

```
public void DoSomething( )
{
    try
    {
        // Entire method body
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        // Five to ten lines of cluttered code
        // for one exception logging call
    }
}
```

I understand that exception handling is opinionated and can even be somewhat controversial. However, I believe that having ***every*** service method follow this template will cause problems down the line as some exceptions get swallowed without addressing the root issue.

I've been reading the Microsoft documentation on the [best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions). I like the idea of error handling on events that happen infrequently and checking for error conditions in code when the event happens routinely.

My question is, is there a way to use an attribute based approach to maintain my exception logging while still being able to handle exceptions on *some* of my methods. I know this is possible to do in MVC and Web API by extending the `System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute` class or the `System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute` class and overriding the OnException methods. For instance, something like:

```
[ExceptionLogger(className, "Index", "name =dbContext")]
public ActionResult Item(int itemId)
{
    var item = _itemService.GetItem(itemId);
    return View(item);
}
```

However, I've yet found a solution in WinForms. Thanks!

Comment: Also as an option if you want to use the feature for your business logic, you still can host Web API in your process and get the benefit of those action filters. But for presentation layer, you should do what is mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: "exceptions get swallowed without addressing the root issue" - yes, a truer thing has ne'er been said.

Comment: You should only ever catch specific exceptions and only those those that you can meaningfully handle. Have a read of [Eric Lippert's Vexing Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: For presentation layer, You can rely on the following events as a central point for exception logging: `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin equivalent to `HandleError` in Windows Forms.

**Service Layer or Business Logic Layer**

For service layer or Business Logic Layer, you still can use Web API. You can host Web API in your process and get the benefit of action filters.

**Presentation Layer**

For presentation layer, you can rely on the following events as a central point for exception logging.

- `Application.ThreadException`
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

Comment: Even if you don't like this fact, the answer is correct.